# com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException

Tags: java, serialization, hazelcast

Am running a OSGI plugin project (with N no of bundles), I have integrated hazel cast in it, 
      i. When I try to add the data as map of string and test bean, It is getting added in hazel cast map but !
      ii. When I try to get the map, Its showing an error as follows,

**com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException**: 
java.lang.*ClassNotFoundException*: com.test.Data cannot be found by **com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.jersey-all_2.10.1.SR1**

**FULL STACK TRACE**

> com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.Data cannot be found by
>   com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.jersey-all_2.10.1.SR1     at
>   com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultSerializers$ObjectSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:201)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:63)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.readObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:285)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:262)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.toObject(ClientProxy.java:156)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.values(ClientMapProxy.java:629)
>     at
>   com.test.commons.db.hazelcast.HazelCastDao.fetchingMapInstance(HazelCastDao.java:126)
>     at com.test.services.agent.dao.DataDao.getData(DataDao.java:79)     at
>   com.test.services.agent.eapi.ExecuteEAPI.executePOSTRequest(ExecuteEAPI.java:105)
>     at
>   com.test.services.ztp.BootStrapLoaderService.getZTPConfigDetails(BootStrapLoaderService.java:55)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)  at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:386)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.data cannot be found by
>   com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.jersey-all_2.10.1.SR1     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    at
>   com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:124)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:113)
>     at com.hazelcast.nio.IOUtil$1.resolveClass(IOUtil.java:122)     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1610)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1769)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultSerializers$ObjectSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:196)
>     ... 60 more

Comment: Have you added the bundle ClassLoader to the Hazelcast Config instance before creating HazelcastInstance itself?

Comment: noctarius, I didnt get you! Please explain me

Comment: It complains about com.test.Data not found, If I were you I would start looking from there like, Is Data class in classpath?

Comment: When creating a HazelcastInstance using Hazelcast::newHazelcastInstance you can give it a Config instance as a parameter. If you don't do that the Config instance is created from classpath available config files. XmlConfigBuilder can create you a Config instance from those files, too. After you got the Config instance you call Config::setConfigClassLoader and set it to your bundle classloader.

Comment: Thanks noctarius, It worked... Awesome buddy

Comment: I'll add it as an answer for others :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating a `HazelcastInstance` using `Hazelcast::newHazelcastInstance` you can give it a `Config` instance as parameter. If you don't do that the `Config` instance is created from classpath-available config files. `XmlConfigBuilder` can create `Config` from those files, too.

After you got the `Config` instance you call `Config::setConfigClassLoader` and set it to your bundle classloader.

```
Config config = new XmlConfigBuilder().build();
config.setClassLoader(getBundleClassLoader());
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

Comment: Noctarius, In case of OSGI, If I give activator as class loader in config, Am able to use all the classes within the bundle and packages added from other bundles, If I try to access the class from another bundle whose class is visible to current bundle but not to my dao bundle, It will throw the same error, Whats the solution for it?

Comment: Currently there's only a workaround available, you create your own classloader that delegates the classloading to the correct classloaders and set this delegating classloader as config classloader. Not a nice workaround but well it is a workaround anyways. Better OSGi integration is in preparation but not yet made it into a special version.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in Harry's links are working. I don't think that's the proper way to do that but I can assure that it's working.

I'll summarize the useful part in the link. This happens due to the class loader picked by Hazelcast, so you can fix it by temporally replacing the class loader of Thread.currentThread() with the class loader of your class. Code sample as below.

```
// Cache the current context class loader
// We can't be sure no-one is using it, so only set it for the hazelcast specific stuff
ClassLoader ccl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
// Get the classloader of a class from inside the bundle
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
// Set it as context class loader
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);

// Hazelcast stuff here

// Reset the context class loader to the cached loader
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ccl);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `<version>3.5.1</version>` Upgrading the hazelcast-all version to `<version>3.12.1</version>` solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same exception when i was trying to cast map value to my cacheEntity like given below.

```java
IMap<Object, UserCacheEntity> imap = hzClient.getMap("userMap");
System.out.println(imap.size());

Collection<UserCacheEntity> coll = imap.values();
coll.forEach(entity -> {
    System.out.println(entity);
});
```

In my case(hazelcast version 3.12.4.), **workaround was to keep `UserCacheEntity` in same package name as it was in cacheServer. i.e, make sure your entity package not changes. It should be same package in client as it was declared in cache server.**