# In OSGI Environment com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException

Tags: java, serialization, osgi, hazelcast

I am running an OSGI plugin project using felix maven plugin with (N bundle), I have integrated hazelcast into it. The class "ConfigurationService" under which hazelcast instance is created is marked singleton and I am using default configuration to create hazelcast instance.

Below is the code snippet.

```
private static ROIConfigurationServer configService;

private HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;


public static ROIConfigurationServer getConfigurationService()throws ConfigServerInitializationException{

if(configService==null){
            synchronized(ROIConfigurationServer.class){
                try{
                    logger.debug("initialized ROIConfigurationServer");
                    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance=Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
                    List<String> imapkeys=new ArrayList<>();
                    IMap<String,String> configGroupKeys=hazelcastInstance.getMap(ConfigurationConstant.CONFIG_GROUP_KEYS);
                    configService=new ROIConfigurationServer(hazelcastInstance,configGroupKeys);
                }catch(Exception exp){
                    logger.error("ROIConfigurationServer initializatiob error", exp);
                    throw new ConfigServerInitializationException("Failed to initialize the ConfigServer",exp);
                }
            }
        }
        return configService;
    }//end of singleton method
```

The singleton class "ConfigurationService" has method to addConfiguration() which add ConfigurationUnit (pojo class) object into hazelcast map object, and getConfiguration()  which get ConfigurationUnit object from hazelcast Map and deployed as bundle "config-service" bundle.

Another bundle called "feature-extender-v3" which uses extender pattern calls addConfiguration() and successfully adds configuration data into hazelcast but on calling getConfiguration() I am getting following error

**Full Stack Trace :**

```
ERROR: Bundle feature-extender-v3 [157] EventDispatcher: Error during dispatch. (com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.getusroi.config.server.ConfigurationUnit)
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.getusroi.config.server.ConfigurationUnit
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultSerializers$ObjectSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:201)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:41)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:276)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.NodeEngineImpl.toObject(NodeEngineImpl.java:200)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapServiceContextImpl.toObject(MapServiceContextImpl.java:281)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.toObject(MapProxySupport.java:1114)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.get(MapProxyImpl.java:82)
    at com.getusroi.config.server.ROIConfigurationServer.getConfiguration(ROIConfigurationServer.java:133)
    at com.getusroi.feature.config.impl.FeatureConfigurationService.getFeatureConfiguration(FeatureConfigurationService.java:41)
    at com.getusroi.feature.config.impl.FeatureConfigurationService.addFeatureConfiguration(FeatureConfigurationService.java:28)
    at com.getusroi.feature.resources.helper.FMIResources.getFeaturesImplementationResource(FMIResources.java:111)
    at com.getusroi.feature.resources.helper.FMIResources.getEventResources(FMIResources.java:37)
    at com.getusroi.feature.extender.FeatureMetaInfoExtender.addedBundle(FeatureMetaInfoExtender.java:89)
    at com.getusroi.feature.bundle.tracker.BundleTracker$1.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:65)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:870)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:791)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:515)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4650)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix$4.run(Felix.java:2123)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.runInContext(Felix.java:2147)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2121)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:942)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.InstallBundle.doExecute(InstallBundle.java:51)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:39)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:477)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:403)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:189)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$4.doRun(ShellFactoryImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$4$1.run(ShellFactoryImpl.java:149)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.JaasHelper.doAs(JaasHelper.java:47)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$4.run(ShellFactoryImpl.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.getusroi.config.server.ConfigurationUnit
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:125)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:114)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.IOUtil$1.resolveClass(IOUtil.java:113)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultSerializers$ObjectSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:196)
    ... 39 more
```

I looked another stack trace with similar issues "[com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033192/com-hazelcast-nio-serialization-hazelcastserializationexception)" but didn't understand. How should I resolve this with default configuration instead of using hazelcast Config?

Comment: while it definitely looks like a classloader issue as sugggested by @Serkan Ozal, I wonder why parent classloader as per osgi classloading scheme is not able to find your `com.getusroi.config.server.ConfigurationUnit`. Can you paste the manifest of feature-extender-v3 to see how class loading might've failed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create Hazelcast instance by giving a specified `Config` with configured classloader (classloader can be set via `setClassLoader()` method) which knows the class `com.getusroi.config.server.ConfigurationUnit`?

Regards.

Comment: Serkan Özal   ... Can you please explain in detail. I have to use default configuration. I am not specifing any hazelcast.xml file in classpath.

Comment: @DeepaliSingh I mean, creating Hazelcast instance with specified Config programmatically.
You can create a default config by "Config config = new Config();" 
and can configure your classloader by "config.setClassloader(myClassLoader);"
and then you can specify this config while creating Hazelcast instance like this "HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);"

Comment: What I need to provide in config.setClassLoader(myclassLoader) code. Can you please provide with some example . I need a help into this.

Comment: @DeepaliSingh You should set a classloader that knows `com.getusroi.config.server.ConfigurationUnit` class

Comment: If I provied something like this :  Confi config=new COnfig();     and  then, config.setClassLoader(ConfigurationUnit.getclass().getClassLoader());   will that work?? or should I used TCCL?? As I have gone through many link , it says TCCL is not a good option for OSGI.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help . it worked. But now I am getting a new problem.. In my ConfigurationUnit class there is an instance variable "Serializable Object" , for this object I am setting an object of class "FeatureImplementation" which is in someOther bundle . When I am trying to get data stored in hazelcast since I have provided the class loader for Configuration unit so its not giving an error but inside configurationunit value for instance variable "Serializable object" whose value is "featureImplementation object" is giving "ClassNotFoundException".

Comment: @DeepaliSingh is it possible to give bundle classloader to `Config` instance instead of `ConfigurationUnit.class.getClassloader()`?
Maybe also try with classloader of current class that creates Hazelcast instance by giving `getClass().getClassloader()` to `Config`

Comment: I  solved the 2nd  problem also, it was just the matter of  correct import, to solve that I used dynamicImport-package.  Anyways your suggestion was very helpful. Thanks again .. :-)